# How can I uppercase a letter after condition in VS CODE?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a yaml file and I have to change some letters to uppercase.

F.e. here I want to change only the words after "value:"

As is:

```
field_map:
      assess_1:
        type: column
        value: assess_1
      assess_10:
        type: column
        value: assess_10
```

As to be:

```
field_map:
      assess_1:
        type: column
        value: "ASSESS_1"
      assess_10:
        type: column
        value: "ASSESS_10"
```

Comment: You can replace the string matched by `(?<=\bvalue: )(\w+)`, which is held in capture group 1, with the contents of that capture group upcased. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fx9fbE/1). `(?<=\bvalue: )` is a *positive lookbehind* that asserts that the string matched by `(\w+)` is preceded immediately by `"value: "`. The word boundary `\b` here ensures that `"value: "` is not preceded by a word character. For example, it prevents matching `"value"` in `"devalue"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use '\U' before substitution.

You can match with `value: (\S+)` and Substitute with `value: \U$1`

[Usage with your given text](https://regex101.com/r/PGauin/1)

**Explanation**

`value: (\S+)` - matches `value:`  followed by a word and consider the word as group 1
`value: \U$1` - replaces the match with leaving `value:` as is and converting the matched group 1 to upper case

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with Multi Cursor:

- select `value:`  (also the space after the `:`)
- use **Selection** > **Select All Occurrences**
- <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> : you are at the start of what you want to uppercase
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> : select till end of line
- <kbd>"</kbd> : enclose selected in `"`
- use command: **Transform to Uppercase**
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> : exit Multi Cursor